# I want to get content from table to array by using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

hey guys i wan to get content from table on website by using selenium

here my first try:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.javatpoint.com/html-table')
texts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td/table")
print(texts)
```

[the retult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25lH8.jpg)

then i want to change it to textcontent by using

```
get_property('textContent')
```

and error said AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_property'

so I want to know how to get table content and turn it to array

ps. python version 3.7.4

Comment: Do you want to extract the table contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for all the text in the table just use `.text`. Like this:

```
from pprint import pprint
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.javatpoint.com/html-table')
texts = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td/table")]
pprint(texts)
```

Output:

```
['Tag Description\n'
 '<table> It defines a table.\n'
 '<tr> It defines a row in a table.\n'
 '<th> It defines a header cell in a table.\n'
 '<td> It defines a cell in a table.\n'
 '<caption> It defines the table caption.\n'
 '<colgroup> It specifies a group of one or more columns in a table for '
 'formatting.\n'
 '<col> It is used with <colgroup> element to specify column properties for '
 'each column.\n'
 '<tbody> It is used to group the body content in a table.\n'
 '<thead> It is used to group the header content in a table.\n'
 '<tfooter> It is used to group the footer content in a table.',
 'First_Name Last_Name Marks\n'
 'Sonoo Jaiswal 60\n'
 'James William 80\n'
 'Swati Sironi 82\n'
 'Chetna Singh 72',
 'First_Name Last_Name Marks\n'
 'Sonoo Jaiswal 60\n'
 'James William 80\n'
 'Swati Sironi 82\n'
 'Chetna Singh 72',
 'Name Last Name Marks\n'
 'Sonoo Jaiswal 60\n'
 'James William 80\n'
 'Swati Sironi 82\n'
 'Chetna Singh 72',
 'Name Last Name Marks\n'
 'Sonoo Jaiswal 60\n'
 'James William 80\n'
 'Swati Sironi 82\n'
 'Chetna Singh 72',
 'Name Mobile No.\nAjeet Maurya 7503520801 9555879135',
 'Name Ajeet Maurya\nMobile No. 7503520801\n9555879135',
 'Element Chrome IE Firefox Opera Safari\n<table> Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes']
```

If you want to use `get_property('textContent')` you can do:

```
from pprint import pprint
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.javatpoint.com/html-table')
texts = [i.get_property('textContent') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td/table")]
pprint(texts)
```

Output:

```
['\n'
 'TagDescription\n'
 '<table>It defines a table.\n'
 '<tr>It defines a row in a table.\n'
 '<th>It defines a header cell in a table.\n'
 '<td>It defines a cell in a table.\n'
 '<caption>It defines the table caption.\n'
 '<colgroup>It specifies a group of one or more columns in a table for '
 'formatting.\n'
 '<col>It is used with <colgroup> element to specify column properties for '
 'each\n'
 'column.\n'
 '<tbody>It is used to group the body content in a table.\n'
 '<thead>It is used to group the header content in a table.\n'
 '<tfooter>It is used to group the footer content in a table.\n',
 '\n'
 'First_NameLast_NameMarks\n'
 'SonooJaiswal60\n'
 'JamesWilliam80\n'
 'SwatiSironi82\n'
 'ChetnaSingh72\n',
 '\n'
 'First_NameLast_NameMarks\n'
 'SonooJaiswal60\n'
 'JamesWilliam80\n'
 'SwatiSironi82\n'
 'ChetnaSingh72\n',
 '\n'
 '  \n'
 '  Name\n'
 '  Last Name\n'
 '  Marks\n'
 '  \n'
 ' SonooJaiswal60\n'
 'JamesWilliam80\n'
 'SwatiSironi82\n'
 'ChetnaSingh72\n',
 '\n'
 '  \n'
 '  Name\n'
 '  Last Name\n'
 '  Marks\n'
 '  \n'
 ' SonooJaiswal60\n'
 'JamesWilliam80\n'
 'SwatiSironi82\n'
 'ChetnaSingh72\n',
 '\n'
 '  \n'
 '  Name\n'
 '  Mobile No.\n'
 '  \n'
 '  \n'
 '  Ajeet Maurya\n'
 '  7503520801\n'
 '  9555879135\n'
 '  \n',
 '  \nNameAjeet Maurya  \nMobile No.7503520801  \n9555879135  \n',
 '\nElement Chrome IE Firefox Opera Safari\n<table>YesYesYesYesYes\n']
```

Comment: Thank you so much,but this method cant get empty td so if i want to check and set it to array with empty td or space what should I do

Answer (score 0):

This will store the table cell content to an array

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get("https://www.javatpoint.com/html-table");


table_rows= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"(//p[contains(text(),'HTML table')]/following-sibling::table[@class='alt'])[1]//tr/td")
x=[]
for rows in table_rows:
    #print rows.text
    x.append( rows.text)
print x
driver.quit()
```

Output

```
<table>
It defines a table.
<tr>
It defines a row in a table.
<th>
It defines a header cell in a table.
<td>
It defines a cell in a table.
<caption>
It defines the table caption.
<colgroup>
It specifies a group of one or more columns in a table for formatting.
<col>
It is used with <colgroup> element to specify column properties for each column.
<tbody>
It is used to group the body content in a table.
<thead>
It is used to group the header content in a table.
<tfooter>
It is used to group the footer content in a table.
```